# Как правильно подключать шрифты CSS?

Tags: css, шрифты

Дан файл к примеру JosefinSans-SemiBold.eot

```
@font-face{

font-family: 'JosefinSans-SemiBold';

src: url('../fonts/WebFont.eot');

src: url('../fonts/WebFont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),

font-weight: ;//Что вот тут прописать для SemiBold

font-style: ;//тут как я понимаю normal?

}
```

такой же самый вопрос про Regular...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> font-family: 'JosefinSans-SemiBold';

Сюда лучше прописывать название семейства без уточнения жирности его начертания. То есть, вместо `JosefinSans-SemiBold` указать `JosefinSans`. Жирность указывается в отдельном свойстве `font-weight`

> font-weight: ;//Что вот тут прописать для SemiBold

Как раз, здесь следует прописать значение `font-weight`. Например, 600 для SemiBold. В другом правиле, когда будете подключать Regular, запишете 400

> font-style: ;//тут как я понимаю normal?

Если начертание не курсивное, то да, нужно указать `normal`

Comment: а как потом, когда вызываешь шрифт @font-family сделать так , чтобы он понял , что мне надо именно semiBold ?У меня и regular и просто bold и тд

Comment: Для элемента в свойстве `font-family` указывается семейство шрифта. А жирность указывается в свойстве `font-weight`. Например, `font-weight: 600` для полужирного

Comment: ```font-family:JosefinSans-SemiBold; font-weight:600 ```? это в простой  css,но к примеру мне надо в font.css несколько файлов подключить. То тип я тогда ко всем прописывают JosefinSans даже если один из них болт , другой регулар , третий light и тд?

Comment: Да.Вот пример. Смотрите CSS: https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/OJLWKav?editors=0110

Comment: я вас понял. Огромное спасибо